# Google Analytics / GA tracking not working in iOS mobile app because of ATT

Tags: ios, mobile, google-analytics, privacy, att

[ASK APP NOT TO TRACK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBsCZ.png)

If a user selects "Ask app not to track" on iOS (ATT feature), I understand it does not send IDFA. However, does it send any other data to GA (ssl.google-analytics.com)?

Has anyone tested this? How to conclude that "Ask app not to track" does not send data to GA?

Impact: GA transaction counts and our internal order management system count have a mismatch. iOS has a huge gap (around 40%).

Other findings: The conversion rate % between iOS and Android still remains the same, however, the absolute count of transactions in iOS is far lesser than our internal order count. Android count matches more than 95%.

GTM for firebase is used to send data to Google Analytics.

Comment: With a rather simple google search like `Does apple do not track still send google analytics` you can find some answers quickly, you question title say that this isn't working, can you rewrite a bit you question paragraph to explain the problem you have

Comment: Hi @BenSouchet, Thanks for the response. Edited as requested. The question I am having is with iOS Mobile App tracking limitation because of ATT. If a user selects "Ask app not to track" on iOS (ATT feature), I understand it does not send IDFA. However, does it send any other data to GA (ssl.google-analytics.com)?